# SpringBoot2.2.1 deployment on cloud server always cannot run report error "Web server failed to start. Port 9090 was already in use."

Tags: java, spring-boot, port, centos7

I am new to SpringBoot and java.I have build a SpringBoot2 app,I want to deploy it in a cloud server. I have specify that port in Application-online.properties like
*server.port=9090* but when I use IDEA MAVEN clean and package command to build a jar then copy to cloud server.
I use

```
nohup java -jar -Dserver.port=9090 -Dspring.profiles.active=online ./mall-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > /root/imooc_mall/mall.log 2>&1
```

then quickly the program exit. the mall.log report :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 9090 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 9090 or configure this application to listen on another port.

[06:25 23:31:32.595] [INFO] [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Noticably, 9090 is the second port I use, before that I use 8081 meet same error. Just like whatever I use any port,it always in use. And I have confirm that the 9090 and 8081 is not in use use *netstat -tulpn* and *lsof -i :8081/9090* . I don't know what's the problem.Hope someone can give some ideals.Thanks advance!

The Environment are Centos7 and SpringBoot2.2.1, Java1.8,and Tomcat is SpringBoot in-build version

Another thing is that I have successed in starting the springboot app at first,But I use kill -9 to stop the program. After that the above errors occurs and never success .I wonder if that have any bad effect on the question.
But I am sure the port is not in use.

Comment: There was [a bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21101) in Spring Boot that meant that any failure to bind was reported as being due to the port being in use. It was fixed in 2.2.7. Perhaps this is the problem you have and the error message is misleading. You could try upgrading and see if that helps. At that time of writing, 2.4.x and 2.5.x are the supported generations.

Comment: Thank you for reply.I have upgraded SpringBoot to 2.2.7 by change                                                                 `<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>` But sadly find Tomcat cannot restart. But I run it locally fine.

Comment: Although I cannot deploy the SpringBoot application on the line with built-in Tomcat, I use standalone Tomcat to run  application successfully on the cloud server. Thank you Andy Wilkinson.

Answer (score 0):

I still use SpringBoot 2.2.1.But not package it with built-in Tomcat.Instead, I install Tomcat server on the server. And Packaging SpringBoot application as war package. And I finally successed in running the application.